# Global variable between functions "undefined"?

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

There must be a better way of doing this, but I'm using Magnific Popup along with an .onclick() function to append a popup, and assign an ID to a div. Here is my code

```
var cardID;

$('.popup-with-zoom-anim').click(function(){
    var cardID = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    console.log(cardID);
});

$('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
    items: {
    src: $('<div id="small-dialog" class="white-popup zoom-anim-dialog mfp-hide"><h1>Delete card?</h1><p>Are you sure you want to delete this payment option? This operation cannot be undone.</p><a href="#" class="card-remove" id="' + cardID + '"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Yes</a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Cancel</a></div>'),
    type: 'inline'
},
        closeBtnInside: true    
});
```

I'm trying to append `cardID` to the anchor with the class `card-remove` within the `magnificPopup` function.

I would prefer not to use global variables, but I've tried putting the `magnificPopup` function inside an `onclick` but it didn't have the intended functionality I desired.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [elementParse event](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api) instead to get the cardID on click:

```js
$('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
  items: {
    src: $('<div id="small-dialog" class="white-popup zoom-anim-dialog"><h1>Delete card?</h1><p>Are you sure you want to delete this payment option? This operation cannot be undone.</p><a href="#" class="card-remove" id="cardID"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Yes</a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Cancel</a></div>'),
    type: 'inline'
  },
  closeBtnInside: true,
  callbacks: {
    elementParse: function(item) {
      console.log(this.ev.attr('id'));
      item.src.find('a[class="card-remove"]').attr('id', this.ev.attr('id'));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/magnific-popup.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="myBtn" class="popup-with-zoom-anim">Open Magnific PopUp</button>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I am keen to avoid using Globals where possible

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need specific element data passed to options of a plugin the easiest way is to initialize inside an `each` loop....even if only one such element exists.

Within `each` you have access to the element instance

```
$('.popup-with-zoom-anim').each(function(){

     var cardID = this.id;
     $(this).magnificPopup({/* same options as in question*/ });     

});
```